# Why socket is being closed in run method?

Tags: java, sockets

Server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public final class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server().start();
}

public void start() {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1200)) {
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                executorService.submit(new SocketHandler(socket));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error accepting connections");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error starting server");
    }
}

public final class SocketHandler implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    public SocketHandler(Socket connection) {
        this.socket = connection;
        System.out.println("Constructor: is socket closed? " + this.socket.isClosed());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Run method: is socket closed? " + this.socket.isClosed());
    }
}
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public final class Client{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1200)) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor: is socket closed? false
Run method: is socket closed? true
```

As you can see from output, when run method is invoked `socket` is closed, but in constructor it was opened.

Question: How to prevent socket being closed in run method, so that I can access its output stream?

Comment: Hint: never leave catch blocks empty. You got a println on the server side; so do at least the same for the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use try with resources with a Socket as the resource, since in this situation since the resource, here the socket, will be closed as soon as the try block exits.

Comment: It sorted the problem. Tnx